# How can I serve an mht file with netcat?

Tags: google-chrome, netcat, mhtml

Due to a bug in chrome (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439832) I want to serve a file through netcat instead of loading it directly. But, when I try to simply do `nc -l -p 8000 < /tmp/file.mhtml` and load `http://localhost:8000` in Chrome, I get the text of the file instead of it being rendered as HTML. The file has a Content-Type header, So I expect it to be served:

```
From: <Saved by WebKit>
Subject: Foo Bar
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2015 06:44:35 -0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/html";
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0B03_4EE56298.243AD9A7"

------=_NextPart_000_0B03_4EE56298.243AD9A7
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Location: https://example.com/foo/bar?q=4
```

Comment: Can you check what headers Chrome picked up by visiting the Developer Console? Are the headers rendered in plain text as well? Does your file have HTTP/1.1 200 OK as the first line for example?

Comment: There are only request headers, no response headers

Comment: You should add the HTTP preamble then (directly to the file for example), so Chrome can read them correctly. At least add `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` at the top of the file.

Comment: I did. Chrome still doesn't show any response headers

Answer (score 2):

Using `netcat` you're serving an MHT file directly over TCP through `netcat`, instead of over HTTP. Chrome does not know how to deal with that since it does not seem to have support for MHTML.

Comment: But that's like opening an HTML file from disk; it does not mean that you can serve that HTML file over plain TCP.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a valid HTTP response:

```
while [ $? == 0 ]; do nc -l -p 8000 -e 'printf "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n"; cat /tmp/file.mhtml'; done
```

Comment: Now I get: nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known